# How to keep the email and password if the browser is refreshed in my keep logged in function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do is to keep the email and password in the modal dialog login page if I click the checkbox button and if I refresh the same page and click the modal dialog again the email and password should be still there.

My problem is if I sign in in my login modal dialoge box and checked the keep me logged checkbox and click the button and refreshed the page again the email and password I've typed are gone it wasn't there anymore.

Does anyone here know how to keep what I typed in the email and password in my modal dialog box if I checked the checkbox keep me logged in button?

Whole html code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
 $unm=isset($_SESSION['email'])?$_SESSION['email']:'default_username';
 $pwd=isset($_SESSION['password'])?$_SESSION['password']:'default_password';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> <!--submit form script-->
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
                $('#sumbit').on('click', function(){
                    window.location.replace("profile.php");
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                });
               $('[name="chkbox"]').on('click', function(){
                  $.post( "savestate.php", { email: $('[name="email"]').val(), email: $('[name="password"]').val() }).done(function( data ) {
                     alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
                  });
               });
        });
        </script>




</head>

<body>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS AND PASSWORD TO LOG IN.</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $unm; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address..." />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $pwd; ?>"" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password..." />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="staylogged" class="checkbox-inline" />
                                                <label>  &nbsp; Keep me logged in</label>  &nbsp; <b>|</b>
                                                <a href="" style="text-decoration:none">  &nbsp; Forgot your password?</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <button type="button" id="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</button>
                                                <button type="button" id="show_signup_md" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Register</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

savestate.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];
    $unm=isset($_SESSION['email'])?$_SESSION['email']:'default_username';
    $pwd=isset($_SESSION['password'])?$_SESSION['password']:'default_password';
?>
```

Comment: If the checkbox is checked you can start a session and then keep your variables in the session array.

Comment: I don't understand.. Do you want to keep user logged in or just save his credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set variables in server side when user clicks check button.Probably by using AJAX.
And then use them in your page when you display the page.

Here is jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
                $('#sumbit').on('click', function(){
                    window.location.replace("profile.php");
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                });
             $('[name="chkbox"]').on('click', function(){
               if(!$(this).attr('checked'))return;
              $.post( "/savestate.php", { email: $('[name="email"]').val(), password: $('[name="password"]').val() }).done(function( data ) {
                // alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
              });
           });
        });
```

Here is  savestate.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];
```

You can reuse in your php page as

```
 $unm=isset($_SESSION['email'])?$_SESSION['email']:'default_username';
 $pwd=isset($_SESSION['password'])?$_SESSION['password']:'default_password';
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Ok So i should add a solution :D

Comment: Yes - an answer should be a solution!

Comment: Don't forget to mention session_start();

Comment: Oh yes :D . Btw Thank you. You prevented me from many downvotes.

Comment: @MADTerry y if i refreshed the page its say default_username and default_password inside the inputboxes?

Comment: @user3656791 Updated. I wrote wrong name of element.

Comment: its still the same...its shows default_username and default_password in the inputboxes everytime i refreshed the page.

Comment: the error now is..if i click the checkbox it says "undefined index: password"?

Comment: @user3656791 Updated.Another typo.

Comment: the password wont save? but the email is save how come?

Comment: i have updated.There was tupo.I typed password as email.Reuse my new code.

Comment: i used it but the placeholder "enter email address and enter password" is changed to "default_password and default_password" in the inputboxes.

Comment: Can you post your post your code in paste bin that will be helpful http://pastebin.com/. Complete code. HTMl,Savesate.php

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use instead jQuery's plugin for cookies?

http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

In general terms, it is a [really bad practice to store the password in the cookie](http://bit.ly/1h446gJ) but if you wan't to do it, I'm no one to tell you not to do it.

Another better solution will be store the information in the session of PHP. [Here is a good tutorial](http://bit.ly/1qRQBKK) of this. Although a still better solution will be [store the session in database](http://bit.ly/1j5cQTM), so your app is stateless.

Using jQuery's plugin will be as easy as:

```
jQuery(function () {
  $("#email").val($.cookie("unm"));
  $("#password").val($.cookie("pwd"));
});
```

In this way, if there is something in the cookie, the value will be that, otherwise, will be blank. Or you can do

```
$("#email").val($.cookie("unm") || "Default value for usermane");
```

To set a default value if the return of that cookie is null (or empty).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use local storage (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) but I recommend using a server side option.